# $4$ dogs have been born in the same week. What is the probability that they were born on different days?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

> $4$ dogs have been born at a dog kennel in the same week. What is the probability that
>   they were born on different days?

I did:
$$\frac{^7C_4}{7^4}$$

But my book says the solution is:
$\frac{120}{7^3}$

What did I do wrong?

EDIT: I copied the problem exactly as it is in my book. If it is missing information, poorly thought or doesn't make any sense, that's not my fault. Typos, mistakes and low quality abound in these schoolbooks.

Comment: This is a specific case of the [Birthday Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem).

Comment: Dogs are mostly multiple births; if a mere 4 dogs are born, they are probably all the same litter, and the odds against them being born on different days is very low.  Looks like the book is very wrong.

Comment: Dog births at a dog kennel are not independent events, the question should clarify that, or you should note that as an assumption in your answer, since it appears you are supposed to make that assumption.

Comment: What is really horrible about this question is not that it's missing information per se, but that it implicitly teaches students to be extremely hand-wavy when dealing with probabilities. It teaches them that you can ask about "probability" without specifying anything about a probability distribution, and that everything is uniform and IID. This leads to statements like "there is a 50:50 chance climate change is caused by humans". And, for everyone who says "assume uniform IID when nothing else is specified", this may work here, but check Bertrand's paradox. Rant over.

Comment: @SashoNikolov Welcome to Portuguese education. Literally every exercise, not just in Maths, is that way. The teachers just tell us to "assume" things.

Comment: @SilenceOnTheWire such problems are pretty much everywhere. Btw, if I had to do this question, yeah I would have assumed that the dogs are not identical. That means out of four specific days chosen, they can be in different considerable orders.

Comment: Everyone is mentioning dogs born in litters, but who says they were born from the same dog?

Comment: Everyone worrying about multiple births is ignoring the [KISS Principle](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle). This is a math problem, not a veterinary longitudinal study requiring a lot of data points of litter size and birth timing. You must use only math and you do not have time for such research.  Because of that, you may safely assume the births are independent without having to be told that.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

The first dog can be born on any day.

The second dog has probability 6/7 of being born on a different day.

The third dog has probability 5/7 of being born on a different day.

The fourth dog has probability 4/7 of being born on a different day.

$$\frac67\cdot\frac57\cdot\frac47 = \frac{120}{7^3}$$

Comment: This answer fails to note the assumption of independent births, which in reality is a rather significant assumption to be making

Comment: One of the most important things to check in relation to probability questions is independence, because yes, many real life and exam questions put that assumption to the test. Common sense is to check for that, not ignore it. When questions are framed in a real life (not abstract) scenario, common sense is to question how the assumptions we have to make actually apply to the real life scenario.

Comment: If the births were not independent, then this question wouldn't be anywhere near as interesting.

Comment: I am dumbfounded this question has gotten so much attention. What happened? I've answered questions far more complicated than this, with far better answers than this, and don't often come up with any upvotes.

Comment: @Kaynex HNQ. Have an upvote and enjoy the ride!

Comment: I have gotten reputation points because people can't decide whether or not the dogs are from the same litter. This is a good day!

Comment: @Kaynex Same thing happens to me. It's almost like a matter of striking gold...

Comment: @Kaynex Haha same here

Comment: It's a matter of answering a "Goldilocks question:" not too difficult that most can't understand it, not too easy that most would consider trivial. Just difficult enough that the answer is beyond their grasp, and just a little nudge gets them over the threshold.

Comment: @Kaynex http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/283851/321647

Answer (score 34):

There is not enough information to solve this problem. If the dogs were from the same litter the probability is very low that they were born on different days. Normally you should be given some assumption like each day of the week is equally likely (reasonable) and independence (unreasonable - does the problem writer have any idea dogs are usually born into litters?).

In a Bayesian sense learning the four dogs were born in the same week will require updating the prior that their births are not correlated. Given the kennel is not that large.

In short, what a **terrible** word problem.

Comment: Did you mean: If the dogs were from the same litter the probability is very **low**.

Comment: @Hand-E-Food yes, fixed

Comment: Why do you assume that they are from the same litter? It seems pretty obvious to me how this question is meant, and your answer does little to help the OP.

Comment: Also, we're not informed if one of the days had a leap second added (or less likely subtracted). If one of the days is longer or shorter than the others than that will obviously affect the probabilities, even if only by 1/ 86400.

Comment: @xLeitix It is only very obvious if you have already seen lots of other problems of the same kind. On the other hand, if you have experience with animals, it is very natural to assume they are born together, because dogs typically have 3-8 puppies at a time, not only one.

Comment: @MikeScott I'd not care much about a leap second, but would take into account a possible $\pm1$ hour for a day light saving switch Sunday.

Comment: This is mathematics?

Comment: In all given problems of this kind you could always ask for more information which would be shifting the probabilities this way or the other. If no information about a condition is given you have to assume equal distribution; that's the only logical assumption then because without knowledge to prefer one or the other lacks reason. Here nobody talked about siblings. Your critique belongs more in the realm of playful riddles where the solver is supposed to include world-knowledge (four eggs are typically not cooked in a row but at the same time). But this question is only about "combinatorics".

Comment: @Alfe If we're talking about probability then understanding the assumptions one needs in order to reduce to combinatorics is absolutely on topic. One can only wonder if this question is baiting the reader to check exactly that given how extremely unrealistic the uniform iid assumption would be if one tried to take the question seriously as more than an envelope to stuff some numbers in.

Comment: @jwg a probability textbook will discuss different distributions and the iid assumption, so yes.

Comment: The problem can be solved, but only if we make the (thoroughly unrealistic) assumption that the dog births are independent events. In short, I agree it is a poor question. However I think people who criticize this answer for NOT automatically making the "independent event" assumption would do well to recognize that highlighting that assumption is more rigorous. Because in the real world, we can't just answer questions like this while making unrealistic assumptions and get anywhere close to predictive power.

Comment: We also weren't told whether the dogs were born in a society that uses the Babylonian 7 day week or the Roman 8 day week. Additionally, we weren't told if the dogs were born on planet earth or some other planet where perhaps a day is a billion years long and they've never even seen day 2 yet. Perhaps there's a time warp anomaly and just before the end of the day you always go back to the beginning of the day, the question didn't rule that out. These ideas are no more nitpicky than the question doesn't say if they are siblings or not.

Comment: @Dunk those ideas are obviously far more nitpicky.

Comment: @djechlin - To whom? Just because you say so. It is obvious from the question NOT BEING ON A RIDDLE SITE that there was no intent that the question is a trick question.

Comment: @Dunk it's not a trick question. I've explained this thoroughly in my answer and in the comments. one should know the assumptions one uses when solving a problem. off you go now.

Comment: @djechlin - Perhaps you should look up the definition of 'assumption'. An assumption is not explicit but is implicitly assumed from the context. The claim that the question wasn't explicit enough only makes sense on a riddle site. My point was that in order to provide complete and total context to remove all doubt and remove every assumption; one would generally have to write a book for each and every question that rules out every other possible interpretation. Or, one can just make the appropriate assumptions based on the context of the question.

Comment: @Dunk independence of samples is a crucial and often overlooked assumption in mathematics, statistics and machine learning. "Don't mix your training data and your test data." Polling the same users twice, grabbing four dogs from a kennel without realizing they might be from the same litter. I just don't even see the point of framing a word problem at all if all of the information in it is intended to be ignored.

Comment: @Dunk when writing a math proof you must state your assumptions. You must not implicitly assume anything you were not explicitly assuming from the start. That's, literally, what an "error" is.

Comment: @djechlin - I get your point and I concede that 'technically' you are correct in everything you have said (other than the 'obviously far more nitpicky' comment). However, once again, the OP's question appears to be a typical math question for practicing application of combinatorial math, not a rigorous math proof or riddle. So expecting all assumptions to be clearly stated is a bit overkill for this particular situation but in another context very well may be required.

Comment: @Dunk http://i.imgur.com/gRk1uZm.gif

Comment: @djechlin: The puzzle says that four dogs have been born at a kennel.  While it does not explicitly specify that those were the only dogs born at the kennel during that week, and the language implies that less strongly than would, e.g. "Four dogs were born at XYZ Kennel during the week of October 12-18, 2016", nothing suggests that the pups were explicitly chosen from separate litters, nor that there were enough pups to prevent the grouping into litters from severely skewing the results.

Comment: Actually, I find it ridiculous to even think about the four dogs being siblings.  If they were siblings, *of course* they weren't (all) born on different days.  The whole question would not be about combinatorics then.  Well, at least *I* never had that thought until reading this answer.

Comment: @Alfe correct, it's only possible to reduce the question to combinatorics if the independence and uniform assumptions are met. Probably, this problem set doesn't really care if the student just skips acknowledging the necessary assumptions to reduce probability to combinatorics. But the "real world," rigorous mathematical proofs, and machine learning and statistics applications all care about this nonobvious assumption being met. So, it's rather sad that the problem *could* have taught to check your assumptions, but instead taught that it's silly to do so.

Answer (score 14):

The denominator, $7^4$, counts the ways to select a day for each dog. So you must do the same in the numerator: count ways to *select a day for each dog* (although, distinct days).

You counted ways to select 4 distinct days for the dogs to be born.

However, there are $4!$ ways to assign the dogs to each of these days.

$$\dfrac{{^7\mathsf C_4}\cdot 4!}{7^4} = \dfrac{7!/3!}{7^4} = \dfrac {120}{7^3}$$

Comment: Right, so my answer would be correct it order didn't matter, right?

Comment: Yes. You could also use $^7P_4$ to reflect the importance of the order..

Comment: No; @SilenceOnTheWire The denominator, $7^4$, counts the ways to select a day for each dog.  So you must do the same in the numerator: count ways to select a day for each dog (although, distinct days).

Comment: @SilenceOnTheWire Order doesn't matter in this question either- you're not given any ordering. In a way, if you include ordering in both the numerator and the denominator, they cancel each other out. So no, your answer wouldn't work, because order already doesn't matter.

Comment: SilenceOnTheWire: Order of what?  I think it would be better to say "if identity of the dogs didn't matter".  But this is problematic because dogs ARE distinguishable from each other, and it is difficult to imagine a realistic way of conducting the experiment that eliminates the need to consider this distinguishability.  @GrahamKemp has already pointed out that your denominator accounts for distinguishability, so your numerator had better do the same.  On the other hand, there are ${^{4+7-1}\mathsf C_4}={^{10}\mathsf C_4}$ ways to put four indistinguishable items in ...

Comment: ... seven distinguishable categories, and if these were all equally likely, then the probability that the items were assigned to different categories would be $\dfrac{{^7\mathsf C_4}}{{^{10}\mathsf C_4}}=\dfrac{1}{6}$.  This calculation might be appropriate in a generalization of [Einstein's non-interacting gas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bose%E2%80%93Einstein_condensate#Einstein.27s_non-interacting_gas), where four indistinguishable, non-interacting bosons could occupy any of seven states of equal energy.  It would not, however, be appropriate for dogs' birthdays.

Comment: @KevinLong: There are probability problems concerning selection where, if you account for all possible orderings of the selected items in both numerator and denominator, the factors that account for ordering cancel out.   I do not see that that is what is going on in this problem, however.

Answer (score 4):

You're mistakenly giving an ordering when you use $7^4$. $7^4$ gives the number of $4$-tuples $(w,x,y,z)$ where $1\leq w,x,y,z\leq 7$ with each number representing a day. You get because there are $7$ choices for each place. But in the numerator, you have no ordering- instead, you're counting the number of subsets (and by definition, sets are unordered) of the set $\{1,2...7\}$ with cardinality $4$. As before, each number represents a day, but you're not assigning a day to each dog.

Each set of $4$ days, e.g. $\{1,2,3,4\}$, which we can think of as Sunday, Monday, Tuesday, and Wednesday, represents multiple assignments of days to dogs. The first dog could be born on any of those $4$ days, the second dog could be born on any of those $3$ remaining days, the third dog could be born on any of those $2$ remaining days, and the last dog has no choice. If we multiply the number of sets of size $4$ by $4!=24$, we get all of the permutations of days represented by those sets, since each one has $24$ permutations. This additional factor gives us the given answer.

Comment: I like the point that this hits on, as I believe it's what the OP needs to understand to overcome this problem. But I think it's not clearly explained; if you can improve the clarity then I'll upvote.

Comment: @Myridium Thanks for the suggestion. Is this better?

Comment: I think it may be too complicated for the OP at this point. I like answers that are understandable on a first pass by dummies like myself. Nonetheless, I appreciate your effort and the focus of your answer, so you get my upvote :)

Comment: "You're mistakenly giving an ordering when you use $7^4$."  Why "mistakenly"?  The rest of your post suggests that it is $C(7,4)$ that is mistaken, not $7^4$.

Comment: @WillOrrick That's true, thanks. I thought about your other post, and then I realized that if the ordering cancelling out part was true, then we'd need $7^4$ to be divisible by $24$. I'd argue, however, that, by having one ordered and one not, you have a mistake, and that you can correct that by ordering the numerator, though I suppose intuitively that you should just have both unordered. Strangely enough, I thought that the number of unordered $7$-tuples of nonnegative integers whose sum is $4$ was $10 \choose 6$, but $\frac{7\choose 4}{10\choose 6}$ doesn't give me the same answer...

Comment: It shouldn't.  Each of the the $\binom{7}{4}$ sets of four days of the week can be ordered in $4!$ ways, but this is not true of the $\binom{10}{6}$ multisets of four days of the week.  Those multisets that are sets have $4!$ orderings, but those with repeated elements have fewer.  Equivalently, the $\binom{10}{6}$ multisets are not equally likely: there are more ways for the four dogs to be born on Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, and Thursday than there are for them all to be born on Monday.  Since the multisets are not equally likely, it doesn't make sense to divide by the number of multisets.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously, the eldest one has nothing to care about getting birth on a 'different' day, so he/she has $C(7,1)$ choices out of $7$ days of a week with the probability equal to $\frac{C(7,1)}{7}=1$.

Comment: You should reconsider your answer. What you want to say? The question is asking something else.

Comment: @Reeshabh Ranjan..I just stated the point where the OP has committed mistake.